# Migrate from Symfony 2.8 to Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony

i migrate my application with SonataBundle from Symfony2.8 to symfony 3.4, all is works perfect but some users of my application are disabled! field enabled is changed to false, any idea!

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe this is a display error that has something to do with [Sonata Boolean Type](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/3-x/doc/reference/form_types.html#booleantype):

> The `boolean` type is a specialized `ChoiceType`, where the list of choices is locked to yes and no.
>
> Note that for backward compatibility reasons, it will set your value to 1 for yes and to 2 for no. If you want to map to a boolean value, just set the option `transform` to true. For instance, you need to do so when mapping to a doctrine boolean.

Have you checked in your database if the users are really disabled?